# Computing $\int_{-1}^{1} x^n \cos(m \pi x) \, dx$ by integrating by parts, twice

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am not a mathematician by trade, but I am doing some research at the moment which requires me to find an integral in terms of another known integral.  I am trying to figure out where I went wrong in my integration, but to my embaressment, it has been a very long time since I last computed a definite integral.

The following is the integral in question, where $n$ is a positive even integer:

$\text{f}(n,m) = \displaystyle \int \limits_{-1}^{1} x^n \cos(m \pi x) \, dx$

I integrate this by parts once:

$\text{f}(n,m) = \dfrac{2 \sin(m \pi)}{m \pi}- \displaystyle \int \limits_{-1}^{1} x^{n-1} \dfrac{\sin(m\pi x)}{m\pi} \, dx$

And then I integrate by parts once more, to get $\text{f}(n,m)$ in terms of $\text{f}(n-2,m)$.

$\text{f}(n,m) = \dfrac{2 \sin(m \pi)}{m \pi} + \dfrac{2 \cos(m \pi)}{(m \pi)^2} - \dfrac{1}{(m \pi)^2} \displaystyle \int \limits_{-1}^{1} x^{n-2} \cos(m\pi x) \, dx$

However, I know that this result is wrong.  I tried testing with a few cases, such as $n=4$ and $m=2$, but it gives a totally wrong answer.  Where did I go wrong in my integration by parts?

Comment: Your integration by parts is wrong!

Comment: @science I knew that much :)

Comment: Are you assuming $n$ and $m$ positive integers?

Comment: $\int u dv = uv-\int v du .$ Take $u=x^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using integration by parts twice you reach to the form

$$f(n,m) = {\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{m}n}{{m}^{2}{\pi}^{2}}}+{\frac {\left( 
-1 \right)^{m}{{(-1)}^{ \,n}}n}{{m}^{2}{\pi }^{2}}}- \frac{n \left( n-1
 \right)}{m^2\pi^2} \int _{-1}^{1}\!{ {{x}^{n-2}\cos( m\pi \,x ) }
}{dx} $$

which gives the recurrence relation

$$ f(n,m)= {\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{m}n}{{m}^{2}{\pi }^{2}}}+{\frac { \left( 
-1 \right) ^{m}{{(-1)}^{n}}n}{{m}^{2}{\pi }^{2}}}-\frac{n \left( n-1
 \right)}{m^2\pi^2} f(n-2, m) .  $$

Answer (score 1):

After you integrated by parts once, the integral on the right-hand side is missing a factor of $n$.

Comment: Yes, and you make a similar mistake in the second integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

The product of an odd function and an even function is an odd function. So $x^n\cos(m\pi x)$ is odd when $n$ is odd, and therefore the integral is zero. For even $n$, the integrand is an even function, so we can write
$$\int_{-1}^1 x^n\cos(m\pi x)= 2\int_0^1 x^n\cos(m\pi x). $$
That should make the computation easier.